# Selecting row by min value and merging

Tags: r, merge, aggregate

This is row selection problem in R.

I want to get only one row in each dataset based on the minimum value of the variable fifteen. I have tried two approaches below, none of them returning the desired output.

For list 1> SPX[[1]] the date.frame is set up like this:

```
SPX1[[1]]
+----------------------------------+---------+------------------------+----------------+
|                                  | stkPx   |          expirDate     |    fifteen     |
+----------------------------------+---------+------------------------+----------------+
| 1                                | 1461.62 | 2013-01-19             |          2     |
| 2                                | 1461.25 | 2013-01-25             |          8     |
| 3                                | 1461.35 | 2013-02-01             |          3     |
| .                                |  .      |  .                     |          .     |
| .                                |  .      |  .                     |          .     |
+----------------------------------+---------+------------------------+----------------+
```

The first approach is aggregating and the merge. As this has to be done for a list the code is in a loop:

```
df.agg<- list() # creates a list
for (l in 1:length(SPX1)){ 
  df.agg[[l]]<- SPX1[[l]] %>%
aggregate(fifteen ~ ticker, data=SPX1[[l]], min) #Finding minimum value of fifteen for ticker
df.minSPX1 <- merge(df.agg[[l]], SPX1[[l]]) #Merge dataset so we only get row with min fifteen value
}
```

I get :

```
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'SPX1' of mode 'function' was not found
```

Another approach, however it just changes all the values of the first column to one, not deleting any rows when merging:

```
TESTER<- which.min(SPX1[[1]]$fifteen) # Finds which row has minimum value of fifteen
df.minSPX1 <- merge(TESTER, SPX1[[1]],by.x=by) #Try to merge so I only get the row with min. fifteen
```

I have tried reading other answers on SO but maybe because of the way the lists are set up this won't work?

I hope you can tell me where I get this wrong.

Comment: would you please clarify the meaning of minimum here? may be small e.g.

Comment: fifteen is a difference between two dates. It is always a positive integer. I therefore wish to find the row where "fifteen" is closest to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
df<- lapply(SPX, function(x) x[x$fifteen==min(x$fifteen),])    
df<- as.data.frame(df)
```

**Edit:**
As suggested by @Gregor-Thomas this will work when there is a tie.

```
df<- lapply(SPX, function(x) x[which.min(x$fifteen), ])
df<- as.data.frame(df)
```

Comment: This is close, but the variable `fifteen` won't be found unless you specify it as a column. I'd suggest `function(x) x[which.min(x$fifteen), ]`. Using `which.min` will also guarantee a one-row result even if there are ties, which I assume OP wants since they say "I want to get only one row".

Comment: I missed it. Corrected now

Comment: The first part works. However, when transforming the list to a dataframe the data is added horizontally so I have one observation and 3900 variables.

Comment: For my case the data frame should be arranged by `df2 <- ldply (df, data.frame)`. ldply is part of plyr package.

Comment: @Anders To change the list do a data frame use `dplyr::bind_rows(list)` or `do.call(rbind, list)` or `data.table::rbindlist(list)`. `plyr` is a little dated, and will cause conflicts if you use the more modern `dplyr`.

Comment: To change the list do a data frame use `dplyr::bind_rows(list)` or `do.call(rbind, list)` or `data.table::rbindlist(list)`. `plyr` is getting pretty dated, and can cause conflicts if you use the more modern `dplyr`.